# How to render string in qweb?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9, qweb

I'm trying to insert and objet value on a element of a qweb template:

My code:

```
<img t-att-src="'/report/barcode/Code128/%s' %(str(order.sequence_number).zfill(18))" 
                        style="width:250px;height:50px;"/>
```

I'm trying to extend the pos receipt to print a barcode....
If I do it like this it work, but i need to replace *mycode* with the formated sequence_code:

```
<img t-att-src="'/report/barcode/Code128/*mycode*'" 
                        style="width:250px;height:50px;"/>
```